# convert sql BETWEEN clause from ANSI 89 into ANSI 92

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join, ansi-sql

I am trying to convert an sql statement from ANSI 89 into ANSI 92 (meaning to transofrm the "(+)" into "OUTHER JOIN")

Here is the code:

```
select a.*, p.price
from article a, prices p
where a.product_id = p.product_id(+)
and trunc(sysdate) + 1 between a.date_from and date_to
and trunc(sysdate) + 1 between p.date_from(+) and p.date_to(+);
```

I know that (+) refers in LEFT or RIGHT JOIN, depending of the possition where it is placed but I cannot get it how to transform the last line (
`and trunc(sysdate) + 1 between p.date_from(+) and p.date_to(+)`
)

Until now, I did the follwoing:

```
select a.*, p.price
from article a
left join prices p
on a.product_id = p.product_id
where trunc(sysdate) + 1 between a.date_from and date_to
```

but I hae no clue how to transform the last condition.

Can someone help with this, please?

Thank you,

Comment: If you use a `left join`, that `(+)` isn't needed anymore.  About the different ansi92 joins, [here's an interesting older post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join?rq=1) you could read. Also, it's possible to use a `between` criteria in the `on` of a `left join` (although rarely done that way)

Comment: `and trunc(sysdate) + 1 between p.date_from and p.date_to;`?

Comment: @LukStorms: my mistake, I forgot an "(+)" into my try. Anyway, the article is good but already knwo the difference among LEFT/RIGHT/INNER/FULL joins. I just want transform the and trunc(sysdate) + 1 between p.date_from(+) and p.date_to(+) in an ANSI 92

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: it is not working. it restricts the rest of the conditions and returns nothing.

Comment: You need to put that into the `JOIN` condition, **not** the `where` condition.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: already done. it returns me extra rows than in ANSI 89 version

Comment: As an aside, the (+) operator isn't ANSI-anything; your original query is Oracle-specific, not ANSI-89

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that each table has a `date_from` and a `date_to`, and that you mean to compare against both ranges.  In that case you left an `a.` off in your example query, so I've added it.  Of course feel free to adjust if that isn't what you meant...

So the obvious difficulty is that if you add

```
and trunc(sysdate) + 1 between p.date_from and p.date_to
```

to the `where` clause, then any "generated `NULL`s" record would be mishandled by that condition.  So instead you can add it to the outer join condition

```
select a.*, p.price
  from           article a
       left join prices p
    on a.product_id = p.product_id
   and trunc(sysdate) + 1 between p.date_from and p.date_to
 where trunc(sysdate) + 1 between a.date_from and a.date_to
```

Semantically this is a bit of a hack, because the date range check on `p` arguably isn't *really* a join condition; but this applies the "outer" semantics to the condition.  The other, more explicit option would be

```
select a.*, p.price
  from           article a
       left join prices p
    on a.product_id = p.product_id
 where trunc(sysdate) + 1 between a.date_from and a.date_to
   and (trunc(sysdate) + 1 between p.date_from and p.date_to
        or p.product_id is null)
```

(You might be able to drop the `or` and just say `between coalesce(p.date_from, trunc(sysdate)) and coalesce(p.date_to, trunc(sysdate)+2))` or something like that, but this assumes that only generated-`NULL` records would have `NULL` for those values - i.e. that no `prices` record actually has a `NULL` in those columns.)